# Does optimal page replacement cause the same number of faults for the reverse string?

Tags: operating-systems, page-replacement

Let $P_1P_2...P_k$ be a page sequence that gives $n$ page faults with the optimal page replacement algorithm. Does the page sequence $P_kP_{k-1}...P_1$ give the same number of page faults. This can be proved quite easily in the case of LRU, and disproved for FIFO. Does it hold for Optimal Replacement?

Comment: LRU is an approximation of Optimal looking in the past and since LRU on reversing gives the same number of page faults, I think it would hold good for Optimal as well. I never came across a page sequence string which violated the claim but I can't think of a way to prove it.

Comment: That question is probably getting more important again. 15 years ago I worked with people having MASSIVE 16 GB RAM backed by hard drives, and they turned VM and therefore paging off. The argument was that this gained 10% speed, and if 16 GB RAM wasn't enough, then page replacements to a hard drive were so slow, it was game over. (4 million pages with 10 millisecond per page replacement = 40,000 seconds). This is somewhat different now with SSD drives.

Comment: An important factor today is that the time to write n pages together is not n times the time to write one page, but can be much less. So you may want to write pages that you don't need to write yet, if this makes the writing faster.

Answer (score 1):

If we let $S^r$ be the reverse of a reference string $S$, then the page-fault
rate for the OPT algorithm on $S$ is the same as the page-fault rate for the OPT
algorithm on $S^r$. Similarly, the page-fault rate for the LRU algorithm on $S$ is the
same as the page-fault rate for the LRU algorithm on $S^r$. [Operating Systems - Galvin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118063333)

More read - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790629/why-on-a-reference-string-and-its-reverse-page-faults-are-same-by-lru-and-optima?rq=1)